# AAD Graph API "unable to update [...] objects [...] originated within an external service"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am working on an application designed to manage Azure Active Directory Users and Groups, as well as their connections, including creating, editing and deleting Users and Groups. The application relies on AAD's Graph API.

Sometimes, when attempting to add a User as a member to a group, I receive the following response from the Graph API:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <code>
        Request_BadRequest
    </code>
    <message xml:lang="en">
        Unable to update the specified properties for objects that have originated within an external service.
    </message>
</error>
```

Specifically, I recently received this response after attempting to add a User created using the Graph API to a Group created using the Graph API.

Is the Graph API the so-called "external service" in this case?

The User has the following properties:

- **Sourced from**: Windows Azure Active Directory
- **Organizational Role**: User

The Group has the following properties:

- **Sourced from**: Windows Azure Active Directory
- **Group Type**: Security group

Am I misunderstanding the error message I received? Or am I missing something else?
Or is this simply a bug?

**EDIT:**
I checked my ability to simply edit the details of each of the above objects (i.e. the Group's description, and one of the User's properties). Both actions were successful... yet I still can't connect the two.

Comment: Any chance these are all DistributionGroups created in Exchange?

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret They are security groups. I am almost certain that they were not created in Exchange, but rather through my c# application using Graph API (though, as time passes, I am less and less certain of how accurate my memory of their creation is...) . I have a couple of other `Group`s created through Exchange that read: `Sourced from: Office 365`, and as I mentioned, the `User` and `Group` in question read `Windows Azure Active Directory`.

Comment: Guy, if you're still hitting this, can you paste the http trace?

Comment: @DushyantGill Thanks for the reply. Since erasing and recreating the users with which there was a problem, I no longer receive this error.